# Audio card; defective salvageable?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, sound-card

The audio in my laptop has stopped working ever since I was heading somewhere in a rainy night with the computer in my backpack. Now, in all probability, when I consider the circumstances, it is probably a hardware problem.

The question is: **How do I verify this?** I tried uninstalling the audio drivers, reinstalling, redownloading, updated my windows, etc. No matter what I do, I get the "No audio devices are installed." message on the one hand, but on the other hand, when I connect the laptop to the TV the audio works (perhaps the laptop utilizes the tv's hardware?), also, when I go to the Device Manager the audio appears.

Is there a method of verification that the hardware of the audio card is faulty in laptops?(I'm willing to open the laptop, provided that I'll have a solid guide for what to look for)

Thank you very much,
Eli

Comment: Reset all BIOS settings to defaults and retest... Look in Device Manager for any unknown devices or anything with an X or ! next to it. You could also try to boot-up a Linux distribution on a USB stick. Also, the audio chipset is embedded on the mainboard, there is nothing to check internally. If the audio hardware is bad, a replacement mainboard is likely the only fix.

Comment: If the audio hardware is bad, a USB audio adapter is a less expensive alternative to replacing the mainboard.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Cheaper maybe... but I actually use my laptop as a "mobile" device, and I sure don't want another dongle hanging off the side. I alkready break 2 or 3 Logitech Unifying Receivers every year, don't really need something else hanging out the side. When you put your laptop in and out of your bag a dozen times a day, it's easy to forget to remove dongles, thumb drivers, etc. once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the battery. Then take the laptop apart, and dry out all parts of the internals with a hairdryer or heatgun. When you’ve done this, there can no longer be any water-induced shorts, and the audio will either work or not work.

If it doesn’t work, you can either buy a high quality USB sound card (30-50$), a low quality USB sound card (5-10$), or send it in for repairs. In the latter case, the repair goons *will* install a new board, and it will cost you plenty.

If you’re real peppy, look for busted electrolytic caps which bulge at the top, and replace any you find. Wouldn’t bet on that, though.

It’s likely some water found its way in via an audiojack and disrupted the audio chip. Very often, it’s not permanent. The fact that your battery isn’t affected means that not much current has been led astray.